# Perplexity, cross/conditional entropy and law of total variance

Tags: variance, entropy, information-theory, cross-entropy, perplexity

I was reading about the concept of [Perplexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perplexity) and was thinking whether there's a connexion with the law of law of total variance, but I couldn't find any reference.

The law of total variance is:

$$Var(Y) = E[Var(Y|X)] + Var(E[Y|X])$$

which can be interpreted as saying that the total variance of $Y$ can be decomposed into a part that is explained by $X$ and the part that is left unexplained (see algo [Explained Variation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Explained_variation) for descriptions in terms of "information gained")

Let's say $Y$ is value of the next letter and $X$ contains all the previous letters written. Then a high ratio of explained vs unexplained variation would mean that the previous letters make it very likely that I predict the next letter with accuracy. This sounds very similar to the idea behind perplexity, so can you think of a way to connect them? (formally or not)

---- Addendum ----

@GeoMatt22 suggested looking at mutual information.

Perplexity can be defined as:

$$ b^{{-{\frac  {1}{N}}\sum _{{i=1}}^{N}\log _{b}q(x_{i})}}$$

where the exponent can be regarded as [Cross entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_entropy).

I still don't quite get the relationship between the law of total variance and [conditional entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_entropy), but it seems they point to the same idea.

Comment: Perhaps [mutual information](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_information) is what you are looking for? (note that entropy is just log perplexity)

Comment: I think you're on the right track! I guess the connection is between mutual information and [cross entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_entropy), which is a way to interpret perplexity. I'll think about it a bit more, let's see if we get any more answers